# web components - custom events on slotchange

Tags: javascript, custom-events, native-web-component

can someone please explain what happens here? am I missing something?

```
#handleClick() {
  this.dispatchEvent(new Event('onClicked'));
}
mySlot.addEventListener('slotchange', () => {
   mySlot.addEventListener('click', this.#handleClick); // doesn't work
   mySlot.addEventListener('click', () => this.#handleClick()); // works
});
...
myCustomElement.addEventListener('onClicked', (e) => {
  console.log(e, e.detail);
});
```

```
#handleClick() {
  this.dispatchEvent(new Event('onClicked', {bubbles: true, composed: true}));
}
mySlot.addEventListener('slotchange', () => {
   mySlot.addEventListener('click', this.#handleClick); // works
});
...
...
myCustomElement.addEventListener('onClicked', (e) => {
  console.log(e, e.detail);
});
```

I know that custom events don't reach the "light-DOM" out of the box, that's why I can understand why we should put "composed: true and bubbles: true".
But why do mySlot.addEventListener('click', () => this.#handleClick()) works without the need of making the event "composable"?

Here is a fiddle to better understand the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/rv6w3xj1/1/

Comment: Can you make it a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just added a fiddle

Comment: Can you add the fiddle as a native Stack Overflow Snippet? That's much more useful and better for future reference.

Comment: It simply has to do with the binding of your method. `dispatchEvent` binds the `this` of the called method to something else, you need to call it with `this.#handleClick.bind( this )` to ensure it uses the right `this` value. Also, why are you storing `#shadow` in a private variable when your `mode` is `open`, therefor making it accessible via `this.shadowRoot` anyway? Seems redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is ***scope***

A Function **reference** gets a different `this` scope than a Arrow Function **definition**,
thus your `this.dispatchEvent` is executed on/from different DOM Elements.

When that element is inside shadowDOM, it needs `bubbles:true;composed:true` to *escape through* the shadowRoot

I pruned your code to the bare minimum, `slot` and `slotchange` have got nothing to do with ***this***

```html
<custom-element><h2>Click SLOT</h2></custom-element>

<script>
  customElements.define('custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
             .innerHTML = `<h1>Click H1</h1><slot></slot>`;
      const addClick = (name) => {
        const el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(name);
        el.addEventListener('click',        this.#handleClick    ); // func REF
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.#handleClick(e) ); // func DEF
      }
      addClick("h1");
      addClick("slot");
    }
    #handleClick(e) {
      console.error(e.type, 'handleClick scope:', this);
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onClicked', {
        bubbles: true, composed: true,
      }));
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('custom-element').addEventListener('onClicked', (e) => {
    console.log("target:", e.target, e.target.getRootNode(), 
                "\ncomposedPath[0]:", e.composedPath()[0]);
  });
</script>
```

You can fix it with *oldskool* `this.handleClick.bind(this)`,
but that is more error-prone than `(e) => this.handleClick(e)`
because most junior DEVs won't understand what is going on with `bind`

### To make 'scope' clearer

Below code displays **where** `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onClicked'` **originates from**
Thus showing what `this` is in `this.dispatchEvent`

When *inside* shadowDOM it needs `bubbles:true;composed` **to *escape* shadowDOM**

The `e.composedPath()` clearly shows a different path the "click" Event passed.
One click came from `<slot>` (inside shadowDOM) the other from your `<custom-element>` (outside shadowDOM)

[image]

```html
<custom-element>
  Slotted Content, click me!
</custom-element>

<script>
  const log = (...x) => document.body.append(document.createElement("BR"), ...x);
  customElements.define('custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `<slot></slot>`;
    }

    #handleClick(e) {
      log("CLICKED! ", "'this' scope is:", this.nodeName);
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onClicked', {
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
      }));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      const mySlot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot');
      mySlot.addEventListener('click', this.#handleClick);
      mySlot.addEventListener('click', () => this.#handleClick());
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('custom-element').addEventListener('onClicked', (e) => {
    log(e.composedPath().map((x, i) => i + " " + x.nodeName));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: in your example you added the event to an h1 element you added to the shadow-dom. I have another usecase, it's about slots

Comment: So what happened when you replaced ``<h1>`` with a ``<slot>`` ?

Comment: nothing, see the question above

Comment: See second code example above. I simplified your code to show ``composedPath()``, One of your clicks originates from the SLOT, the other click from your CUSTOM-ELEMENT.